# This CSS :is() Selector Isn't Working As I Think It Should

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why does the CSS selector `.a ~ .b :is(body .b .c .d)` match `.d` in the following simple HTML markup when surely the space between the first `.b` and `:is()` is a descendant combinator so the selector should be trying to select any `.d` that is a descendant of a `.c` that is a descendant of a `.b` that is a descendant of `body` which (due to the space between `.b` and `:is`) is a descendent of any `.b` that is a following sibling of a `.a`?

`body` is not a descendant of `.b` however `.d` IS selected and `.d`'s background-colour is set to chartreuse.

I thought that the selector list inside `:is()` or `:where()` is relative if it starts with a combinator (e.g. `+`, `>`, `~`) else it is given an implied descendant combinator.so `body .b .c .d` should be matched only if they are **descendants** of `.b` which they're not (`.c .d` are but not `.b .c .d` nor `body .b .c .d`)

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b">
  <div class="c">
    <div class="d"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.a {--bc: red;}
.b {--bc: green;}
.c {--bc: blue;}
.d {--bc: orange;}

:is(.a,.b,.c,.d) {
  aspect-ratio:1;
  border: 3px solid var(--bc);
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.a ~ .b :is(body .b .c .d) /* this colours .d but why? */
/* .a ~ .b :is(.b .c .d) -- so does this */
{
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

I tried the above HTML and CSS and was expecting `.d` to not be selected however the fact that it is has pulled the "how I think CSS works" rug from under me.

**Note:** I know the `:is` isn't necessary with only one selector list, the CSS that originally started me investigating this does have multiple selector lists inside the `:is()` but first I need to understand what is going on with just this one before I can start adding more selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of `:is()` isn't 100% correct.

```
.a ~ .b :is(body .b .c .d)
```

means select any element that match the selector

```
.a ~ .b *
```

AND also match the selector

```
body .b .c .d
```

What is inside the `:is()` has no relation with the outside part and this is a common mistake that everyone make because you see the selector as:

```
.a ~ .b :body .b .c .d
```

But it's not.

So you will select any `.d` element that is a descendant of `.b` and also a descendant of `body .b .c`

---

Another example to see the difference:

```css
.a > .b > .c {
  /* I will select the .c element */
}

.a > :is(.b > .c) {
  /* I will select nothing! */
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
 <div class="b">
  <div class="c">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Both selectors aren't the same. The second one means select any direct descendant of `.a` that is a `.c` element and a direct descendant of `.b`.

A good reading for more detail: https://www.bram.us/2023/01/17/using-is-in-complex-selectors-selects-more-than-you-might-initially-think/

Comment: Thank you. I'm not going to lie but I genuinely dreamt (more of a nightmare) about everything I *thought* I knew about CSS slipping through my fingers. 

I had to read your answer twice to start to start to see what you meant; the article you linked to helped to clarifying things further.

I still think, at a cursory glance it's a little counter-intuitive. I can't just glance at the selector, I have to work my way backwards through it; maybe after a while using it it will be quicker to grokk.