# What does trailing `&` mean in CSS nesting selectors?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Example 1 (from [MDN Nesting Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Nesting_selector)):

```css
.card {
  /* .card styles */
  .featured & {
    /* .featured .card styles */
  }
}

/* the browser parses above nested rules as */

.card {
  /* .card styles */
}

.featured .card {
  /* .featured .card styles */
}
```

The transformed version has a whitespace character between `.featured` and `.card`.

Example 2 (from [MDN Nesting Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting#appended_nesting_selector)):

```css
.card {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  & h2 {
    /* equivalent to `.card h2` */
    color: slateblue;
    .featured & {
      /* equivalent to `.featured.card h2` */
      color: tomato;
    }
  }
}
```

There is no whitespace between `.featured` and `.card`.

And the [w3 doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/#nest-selector) says `&` is equivalent to `:is()`. It's consistent with first example but not the second example.

I've tested both examples and they are absolutely correct!

And I've tried moving off the whitespace surrounding `&` in example 2. If I move off the left one, it does not work any more. If I move off the right one, nothing different.

I cannot find any docs for multiple level nesting selectors when using `&`. Can any one explain this behavior?

Comment: The example further up the MDN page, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting#appended_nesting_selector, says the opposite, that `.foo { .bar & {` was equivalent to `.bar .foo`, so it is probably just an _error_ in the other example you are referring to.

Comment: @CBroe Original link of example 2 provides a playground, and I have also tested it on my local environment, it correct. It's really weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the logic of replacing with `:is()` you get the following

```css
.card {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

:is(.card) h2 {
  color: slateblue;
}

.featured :is(:is(.card) h2) {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<article class="card">
  <h2>Card 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</article>
<article class="card featured">
  <h2>Card 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</article>
<article class="card">
  <h2>Card 3</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</article>
```

Now the trick in the second selector is that you will select a `h2` element that is descendant of `.featured` and also descendant of `.card`. So the combination of `.card h2` and `.featured h2` and in the doc they said it's equivalent to `.card.featured h2` which isn't accurate because you can also have the following

```css
.card {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

:is(.card) h2 {
  color: slateblue;
}

.featured :is(:is(.card) h2) {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<article class="card">
  <h2>Card 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</article>
<article class="card">
 <div class="featured">
  <h2>Card 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="card">
  <h2>Card 3</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</article>
```

Note how I moved `.featured` into another element and the selector still works.

So the selector works fine and the equivalence is true for that particular case BUT not in general. They should probably update the explanation to avoid the confusion.

---

It's also important to note that the below aren't equivalent

```
.featured :is(:is(.card) h2)
.featured .card h2
```

Related: [This CSS :is() Selector Isn't Working As I Think It Should](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76839506/8620333)

Comment: Thanks you! The blog attached in the related link helps a lot.

FWIW, here is the link: https://www.bram.us/2023/01/17/using-is-in-complex-selectors-selects-more-than-you-might-initially-think/#nesting