CSS ":is()" pseudo-class with relative selectors
I want to style specific "sections that are directly inside the body" and "sections that are directly inside a div directly inside the body" with the ":is()" pseudo-class, without the redundancy (with relative selectors).
I have the following code in a index.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Test :is() Selector</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>Section directly inside the body (styled).</section>
    <div>
      <section>Section directly inside a div which is directly inside the body (styled).</section>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <section>Section directly inside a div which is directly inside another div which is directly inside the body (not styled).</section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

and the following CSS in a style.css file:
body > :is(section, div > section) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

I tried searching about, but I was unsuccessful because all searches with the ":is()" pseudo-class and relative selectors send me straight to the relative selectors documentation, since "is" is a very common word without special characters.
This is my first question in stack (although I read this site every day for a long time), but what I need is some complex selector without redundancy that would have the same result as this CSS:
body > section, body > div > section {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}


Where's the redundancy? Your is() example is pretty simple. You could do the same with nesting, but to no real advantage.

I’m not quite clear what the problem is. Is it that your :is doesn’t work (doesn’t pickup the div’s child section)?

:is(body, body > div) > section appears to work.

@CBroe yes, it worked, I wasn't really sure about the use of ":is()" pseudo-class, but with the @Temani Afif's links below I was able to understand, probably from now on I will use this pseudo-class more in parent selectors rather than child selectors.

@CBroe Yeah that selector does indeed work, I explored why in detail with my answer and now understand it better myself as well

You can use & and :is() like below:


body {
   :is(&, & > div) > section {
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
}
<section>Section directly inside the body (styled).</section>
<div>
  <section>Section directly inside a div wich is directly insdie the body (styled).</section>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <section>Section directly inside a div wich is directly inside another div which is directly inside the body (not styled).</section>
  </div>
</div>




Do you have any idea why :is(&, & > div) > section works whereas written the other way around as & > :is(div > section, section) doesn't?

@ZachJensz https://stackoverflow.com/a/76839554/8620333

That's exactly my case, I was using nesting selectors to make my CSS code, this will fit perfectly in my code. From what I could understand from the bram.us page, the :is(&, & > div) > section selector will match something like :is(:is(body), :is(body) > div) > section right ? Or did I get it wrong ?

If you move your selector around, you can get it to work:


:is(body, body > div) > section {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
<section>Section directly inside the body (styled).</section>
<div>
  <section>Section directly inside a div wich is directly insdie the body (styled).</section>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <section>Section directly inside a div wich is directly inside another div which is directly inside the body (not styled).</section>
  </div>
</div>



If I'm understanding your question correctly (edit your question for clarity otherwise):
You want to achieve this behaviour:
body > section, body > div > section {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

But you want to make it more concise by using the :is() pseudo class, and when you say "without redundancy" you mean keeping the selector DRY?
The current DRY selector you have doesn't work correctly:


body > :is(section, div > section) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
<section>Section directly inside the body (styled).</section>
<div>
  <section>Section directly inside a div wich is directly insdie the body (styled).</section>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <section>Section directly inside a div wich is directly inside another div which is directly inside the body (not styled).</section>
  </div>
</div>



Think of :is() globally, as though it can't see the rest of the selector outside itself.
This is your selector:
body > :is(section, div > section)

Let's run it against the HTML element that gives unexpected results:
<body>
  ...
  <div>
    <!-- Testing this section element -->
    <section>
      Section directly inside a div wich is directly insdie the body (styled).
    </section>
  </div>
  ...
</body>


The element is a section, or a section and a direct child of a div ✅
The element is a direct child of body ❌

Given your requirements are to target:

"Sections that are directly inside the body" and "sections that are directly inside a div directly inside the body"

We can change the selector around to:
:is(body, body > div) > section

Let's run it against the HTML element that gave unexpected results:
<body>
  ...
  <div>
    <!-- Testing this section element -->
    <section>
      Section directly inside a div wich is directly insdie the body (styled).
    </section>
  </div>
  ...
</body>


The element is a section ✅
It's a direct child of body❌ or body > div✅

